# Multiple voting possible on the same post under specific (?) conditions

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I downvoted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37533895/bound-dbgrid-to-custom-component) question on 28-07-2016 from [95.70.-.-]. Later that night, when at home, I noticed I somehow failed to downvote (missing orange color on down-arrow in the browser) and downvoted it from [195.174.-.-].

Later I thought of looking at the timeline and there are two consecutive downvotes:

[image: timeline]

I find it highly unlikely that I tried to downvote but failed and around that time someone else downvoted it (the question being non-active at the time). I hope this can be verified.

I don't know what specific circumstances are required to be able to do this. What I can think of as being out of the ordinary are:

- the question being closed
- the question being closed by the voter
- voter is from an IP behind one of a carrier grade NAT ([100.75.136.172] behind [195.174.-.-]).

PS: If the 3rd item is of any relevance at all, I won't be able to test it again.

Comment: Do you have another account?

Comment: @Servy - Nope. I have this account only.

Comment: Do both downvotes show up in your voting history in your profile?

Comment: @Servy - No, my profile shows only one downvote. I can include a picture if it would help.

Comment: I would advise you not to post it publicly; that's private for a reason.  SE will be able to see it, if it gets to that point.

Comment: Ok, I'll follow advice.

Comment: @yellow - Nope. I don't donwvote frequently actually, there's one other downvote that day to a post from a different user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only one of those downvotes is yours.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for looking and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz No worries. Doesn't hurt to make sure nothing's broken. :)